# imwrite giving inconsistent error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, strcat, imread

I wrote a code to clean and print multiple images,

```
data_1=csvread(data)
for h=1:30
    im_old=imread(strcat('catches\image_generator (',int2str(h),').png'));
    im_bw=func_bw(im_old);
    im_2=func_clean_tr(im_bw);
    [im_3a,im_3b]=edge_trial(im_2);
    da=data_1{h,2};
    name=strcat('trrr\',da,'trial.png');
    imwrite(im_3b,strcat('trrr\',int2str(h),'trial.png'));
end
```

There is a particular problem. The imwrite works when the parameters are:

`imwrite(im_3b,strcat('trrr\',int2str(h),'trial.png'));`

But it wont work when I give the parameters as:

`imwrite(im_3b,strcat('trrr\',da,'trial.png'));`

I cross checked that `da` is a 1x1 string and `strcat('trrr\',da,'trial.png')` is also a 1x1 string.
The error shown is:

> Error using imwrite>parse_inputs (line 510)
>
> A filename must be supplied.

No idea why `imwrite` is treating two strings differently...

Edit1: my data_1 reads like:
1,X55N3
2,PQZXS
3,HDDS3...
Also, value of da=data_1{h,2}; is "X55N3"

Comment: It seems to me that MATLAB made things more complicated by introducing the string object and the double-quote. Note that the single quote and the double quote are different things, and create different type objects. If `da` is a string, you are concatenating it with two char arrays into `name`. I don't know what this will do, but it's probably something unexpected. Did you print `name` to see what it looks like?

Comment: Maybe `name` becomes a string, but `imwrite` expects a char array?

Comment: Thanks, i just read input of `imread` is allows only char array and no strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB is still sort of [transitioning to the new `string` class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html). Traditionally, MATLAB has always used `char` arrays where you need a string. They have introduced the `string` class in R2016b, and haven't updated all functions in all toolboxes yet to also take a `string` where they used to take a `char` array.

I'm using R2017a, and see this when using `imread` with a string:

```
>> imread("cameraman.tif");
Error using imread>parse_inputs (line 450)
The file name or URL argument must be a character vector.

Error in imread (line 322)
[filename, fmt_s, extraArgs, was_cached_fmt_used] = parse_inputs(cached_fmt, varargin{:});
```

However, this works:

```
>> imread(char("cameraman.tif"));
```

So your solution is to convert the `string` into a `char` array:

```
imwrite(im_3b,char(strcat('trrr\',da,'trial.png')));
```

or:

```
imwrite(im_3b,strcat('trrr\',char(da),'trial.png'));
```